# Access elements from nested array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume I have the following array

```
test=np.asarray([
    [[ 0.26139668,  0.271985  ,  0.89647514,  0.10352486],
    [ 0.30488212,  0.31384717,  0.84089744,  0.15910256],
    [ 0.32112577,  0.32958562,  0.79216727,  0.20783273]],
    [[ 0.6017121 ,  0.60530397,  0.49432092,  0.50567908],
    [ 0.61610247,  0.61954059,  0.49649699,  0.50350301],
    [ 0.63149809,  0.63477652,  0.49945702,  0.50054298]],
    [[ 0.6017121 ,  0.60530397,  0.49432092,  0.50567908],
    [ 0.61610247,  0.61954059,  0.49649699,  0.50350301],
    [ 0.63149809,  0.63477652,  0.49945702,  0.50054298]],
    [[ 0.6017121 ,  0.60530397,  0.49432092,  0.50567908],
    [ 0.61610247,  0.61954059,  0.49649699,  0.50350301],
    [ 0.63149809,  0.63477652,  0.49945702,  0.50054298]]])
```

Now the result I am looking for are in the first column of each element from `test`. So basically I need `test[0][:,0]` and `test[1][:,0]` ... and finally `test[3][:,0]`.

I am sure this can be done without a for loop, or not?

Since notation `[:]` should mean all elements from beginning till end I even tried `test[:][:,0]`. That didn't work. `test[:,0][:,0]` wasn't any better either.

So, what would be the alternative to a for loop?

---

The result should be:

```
    [0.26139668, 0.30488212, 0.32112577, 0.6017121, 0.61610247, 0.63149809,
 0.6017121, 0.61610247, 0.63149809,0.6017121, 0.61610247, 0.63149809]
```

Or anything similar to that. (I only need those numbers from the whole array).

Comment: show how should look the final result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest OP edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a 3D array so just pass the 0 to the third axis:

```
In [9]: test[:, :, 0]
Out[9]: 
array([[ 0.26139668,  0.30488212,  0.32112577],
       [ 0.6017121 ,  0.61610247,  0.63149809],
       [ 0.6017121 ,  0.61610247,  0.63149809],
       [ 0.6017121 ,  0.61610247,  0.63149809]])
```

If you want them all in one array you can just `ravel` the slice:

```
In [11]: test[:, :, 0].ravel()
Out[11]: 
array([ 0.26139668,  0.30488212,  0.32112577,  0.6017121 ,  0.61610247,
        0.63149809,  0.6017121 ,  0.61610247,  0.63149809,  0.6017121 ,
        0.61610247,  0.63149809])
```